# Ajax call to spring controller not returning into success

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I am using ajax post with parameters to spring mvc controller,data is binding well but not returning into success.Response is going to another page.

I am calling ajax from a modal and success message need to be returned into same modal.

Following is my ajax call,

```
$.post({
url : 'saveEmployee',
data : $('form[name=employeeForm]').serialize(),
processData: false,
success: function (resp) {
    alert("hello");
},
failure: function (resp) {
    alert("hello1");
}
})
```

Following is my controller code,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void Insert(ModelMap model, Principal principal,HttpSession session,@ModelAttribute @Valid Profile profile,
         BindingResult result) {
    System.out.println("profilec "+profile.getRashi());

}
```

Data is getting binded well but, empty page is returned as response, success response need to be returned to same modal.

Comment: *"Response is going to another page."* - Can you clarify what you mean by that?  If the browser is navigating to another page then that's happening outside the scope of the code shown.  AJAX calls don't navigate the user to a new page.  Also, is `failure` really an option jQuery uses?  Shouldn't that be `error`?  And if the response from the server is indeed not what you expect it to be, then what *is* it?  In your browser's debugging tools check the actual response to the AJAX call.

Comment: Browser is navigating to a empty page.I too wonder why this is happening like this.I dont have the other code than I posted.

Comment: Well, something other than the code posted is doing that.  You’ll need to provide a more complete (but minimal) example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: What you said is true David, some other code is executing

Comment: I rectified it now it is working well, thank you